# Erro import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python

O import numpy as np dá bem mas esse aí dá esse erro e não sei como o resolver(abrir o link):
- http://prntscr.com/o2txe8

Answer (score 1):

Antes de importar o `matplotlib` tenta rodar isso:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Segundo [essa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052831/matplotlib-dll-load-failed-when-import-pylab#1052910) e a [documentação](https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend), os backends são responsáveis pela renderização dos gráficos, mas alguns não permitem que haja interação com a interface de usuário. Quando você seta o backend pra `Agg`, você conseguirá apenas salvar a imagem e não visualizá-la com o `plt.plot` se eu não me engano.

[Aqui](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/index_backend_api.html) tem uma lista dos backends disponíveis pra você dar uma olhada e testar se interessar. (: